# Как try catch вмонтировать в калькулятор?

Tags: c#

Написал такой простой калькулятор. Мне нужно сюда добавить вычисление корня, а также использовать механизм `Try/Catch`. По идее, `Try/Catch` обрабатывает исключения, такие как деление на 0 т.д., но не знаю, как его здесь реализовать. Буду благодарен, если объясните на коде наглядно.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double a, b;
            char z;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите 1 число ");
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите действие (+, -, *, /) ");
            z = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите 2 число ");
            b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (z)
            {
                case '+':
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", a, b, a + b);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}={2}", a, b, a - b);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}", a, b, a * b);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}={2}", a, b, a / b);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка");
                    break;
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _не знаю, как его здесь его реализовать буду_ - а вы хоть изучали try/catch?

Comment: ну как изучал так примерно показывали

Comment: я так понял здесь нужно обрабатывать деление на 0 и если добавить корень это тоже

Comment: @timur получиться что-то сделать или написать заново все?

Comment: Изучите, как работает `try/catch` в принципе и Вам сразу станет понятно, как применить его здесь.

Comment: @V-Mor try/catch разобрался осталось разобрать корен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```csharp
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            double a, b = 0;
            char z;
            Console.Write("Введите 1 число ");
            a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Введите действие (+, -, *, /, s) ");
            z = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            Console.WriteLine();
            if (z != 's')
            {
                Console.Write("Введите 2 число ");
                b = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            switch (z)
            {
                case '+':
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", a, b, a + b);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}={2}", a, b, a - b);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}", a, b, a * b);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}={2}", a, b, a / b);
                    break;
                case 's':
                    Console.WriteLine("sqrt({0})={1}", a, Math.Sqrt(a));
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка");
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine("{0}+{1}={2}", a, b, a + b);  здесь ошибка говорит что "Серьезность Код Описание Проект Файл Строка Состояние подавления
Ошибка CS0165 Использование локальной переменной "b", которой не присвоено значение. 
"

Comment: @VenDETTA исправил код.

Comment: Спасибр большое

Answer (score 0):

Добавить к строке, где возможно деление на ноль, блок try/catch:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}={2}", a, b, a / b);
}
catch(DivideByZeroException) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ошибка - на ноль делить нельзя!");
}
```

Comment: а как можно добавить сюда вычисление корня?

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Для корня придётся немного переписывать программу - вам надо будет проверять действие и не требовать ввода второго числа. А так - ну такой же case, только придумать, как вы корень собрались обозначать при вводе. А вычисление корня `Math.Sqrt`